# A countable dense set of irrational numbers.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I think the following is a countable dense subset of irrational numbers. I request you to verify this.

Since $\Bbb R -\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, for every rational number $r$ there is a sequence of irrational numbers, which I will denote by $(\alpha_k^r),k\in \Bbb N$ such that $lim(\alpha_k^r) = r$. For a fixed $r\in\Bbb Q$, the set of points 
$ \{ (\alpha_k^r)|k\in\Bbb N \} $ must be infinite, otherwise some irrational number would be equal to $r$. Also $r\in\overline {\{ (\alpha_k^r)|k\in\Bbb N \}} $. Now consider the set, $$\Gamma = \bigcup_{r\in\Bbb Q} \{ (\alpha_k^r)|k\in\Bbb N \}\subset \Bbb R-\Bbb Q$$ which is a countable union of countable sets and hence countable. And because of the previous remarks,  $\overline \Gamma = \Bbb Q$ . But $\overline{ \Bbb Q} = \Bbb R$ and $\overline{\overline \Gamma} = \overline\Gamma .$ So, $\overline\Gamma = \Bbb R. $

Comment: Good work. This is indeed a countable dense set of irrational numbers.

Comment: Not an answer since I haven't checked your proof. But why not just show that the set of all rational multiples of $\sqrt{2}$ is dense?

Comment: $\bar\Gamma $ is not $\mathbb Q $.

Comment: I think you mean $\overline\Gamma\supseteq\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @Ethan Or, even easier, the result of translating $\mathbb Q $ by $\sqrt2$.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof is correct, though it could be directer: $f(x) = x + \sqrt{2}$ is continuous from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself.

So $\mathbb{Q}$ being dense in $\mathbb{R}$ implies that $f[\mathbb{Q}]$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ as well. And this is a set of irrationals, as $q + \sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}$ implies $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}$, quod non.

We could also have used $f(x) = x\sqrt{2}$ for $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$, of course. Etc. etc.